# CSRF Failes when testing django using postman

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, django-csrf

I have a django (rest_framework) application in which i just added some authentication. Creating an account and logging in with the account went well for the first time but then the trouble began.

Right now whenever or however i try to register/login/logout i instantly get an error message saying that the csrf verification failed or the token was missing.

So i started to find out what it meant and came to the conclusion that it is quite important for authentication. It is unclear to me how i can get the application authentication system working without damaging the security.

**Can someone explain to me how i can communicate with my application without compromising the csrf token. (for example in Postman)**
Thanks in advance!

*My code is pretty standard django auth code*

```
authentication = [ 
    url(r'^status/$', StatusView.as_view()),
    url(r'^register/$', RegisterView.as_view()),
    url(r'^login/$', LoginView.as_view()),
    url(r'^logout/$', LogoutView.as_view()),
]

--- views.py ---------------

class RegisterView(APIView):
def post(self, request: Request):
    acc = authentication.AccountSerializer(data=request.data)
    helper.validate_serializer(acc)
    return Response(acc.data)


class LoginView(APIView):
    def post(self, request: Request):
        username = request.data.get("username", "")
        password = request.data.get("password", "")
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return Response({"message": "Login successful", "account": authentication.AccountSerializer(user.account).data})
        else:
            return APIException(detail={"message": "Login unsuccessful"})


class LogoutView(APIView):
    def post(self, request: Request):
        logout(request)
        return Response({"message": "Logout successful"})


class StatusView(APIView):
    def get(self, request: Request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return Response({"message": "User is authenticated"})
        else:
            return Response({"message": "User is not authenticated"})
```

Comment: you need to set proper content-type in postman. The crsf error simply means that you're sending html/form data format, where it should be json instead. Please read more about setting content type in postman.

Comment: unfortunately i did check this and i am definetely using application/json to send the data, both in the raw body i set the type to application/json as wel as in the headers

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing cookie from postman and see. If your problem is solved, try not to use session authentication and use exempt csrf decorator for a vie (caution: csrf exempt is risky but for development , you can do that =